# JQuery Event for changing tabs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a web application that uses nav-tabs in bootstrap. It has 4 nav-tabs that has different tab-contents. My problem is, I want to know what nav-tab did/will the user choose or click among the 4 tabs and it should change every time the user clicks other tabs, but I don't know what JQuery event should I use. This is the html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="select-tab">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="select-tab">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="select-tab">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" class="select-tab">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
       //tab1 contents...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
       //tab2 contents...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
       //tab3 contents...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
       //tab4 contents...
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the JQuery code:

```
$('.select-tab').on("change",function(){
    alert("1");
}).change();
```

What I did in the JQuery code is that I used "onchange" event and, I want to alert on page load of the website and every time the user navigates to different tabs. But when I tested it, the alert pops-up four times. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Am I using the wrong JQuery event?

Note: I want to know also which among the four tabs was selected by the user. Instead of  "1", it should alert the tab chosen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change and alert on the click of different tabs here is another approach that you can make use of [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V84Gb/)

Code Snippet:

```
$('.nav-tabs > li > a').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(1);
});
```

Comment: How can I know if what tab has been chosen?

Answer (score 2):

From the markup, it looks like you are using bootstrap tabs so look at the [tabs show event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) like

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
})
```

Comment: This works when I choose the other tabs but it doesn't alert the default tab on the page load..

Comment: @user3815765 then after registering the handler try `$('.active > a[data-toggle="tab"]').trigger('shown.bs.tab');`